# What are the .NetCore Analyzers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependencies

I'm working on a .NetCore 2.2 project, my question is about the folder `Analyzers` in the `Dependencies`, What are these,

And in some cases, they have a warning, which makes all `dependencies` folder has a warning.
Okay, it has no effect on the build on Runtime.

- What are the `analyzers`?
- Why they have warnings in some cases?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are roslyn analysers. They help you maintain high code quality.
Library authors for instance can use analyzers to raise errors/warnings/suggestions when users write less-than-ideal or plain low quality code.

If you have the warning sign, your project most likely also has warnings on build. You may expand the node in the question's screenshot to see a list of warnings and start addressing them.

The Visual Studio integration is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#analyzers-in-solution-explorer).
Once you're done clearing the warnings you may also consider using the [FxCop analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/install-fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2019).